# Driving coils of miniature stepper directly with IO pins?

Tags: stepper-motor

I have a bunch of those minature 2 phase bipolair stepper motors from [aliexpress](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/1005002333759250.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.2aa36d1aK1dgOd&algo_pvid=a44581d7-8492-4528-9ee6-2a24b0618ff7&algo_exp_id=a44581d7-8492-4528-9ee6-2a24b0618ff7-17&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000020134589320%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B0.92%3B-1%3B1.83%40salePrice%3BEUR%3Bsearch-mainSearch).

The motors are rated as 5V devices and I measured a coil resistance of 14.8 Ohm. I have read on several places that people directly connected the coils to the IO pins.

So obviously I had to exceed the absolute maximum parameters as well. I connected the coils to four digital IO pins of an arduino Nano board and it actually works (so far, that is).

I tried adding a 100 Ohm resistors in series to limit the current but that is too much.

I never power the coils longer than 2ms. And I am not sensing any heat development anywhere.

What I am wondering: will the inrush currents do actual damage, can I expect a shorter lifetime of the uControler and does the power decrease during roratation of the rotor?

I would like to use an attiny45 to power these motors and I would prefer not to use an H bridge chip as it would double the size of my PCB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inrush current is unlikely to be a problem.  Voltage spikes while turning off is a bigger concern.  Diodes across the coils would be a good idea.

Comment: Would the internal clamping diodes not suffice in this?

Comment: Often times not, they are very tiny.  This is the part most likely to burn out in your IC.

Comment: I will take up 4 diodes in me design, thanks